# Strapi Deployment Issue - Error: Could not load js config file /home/ubuntu/.......: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, strapi

Followed the simple guidelines proiveded via Strapi
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/amazon-aws.html

I'm repetitively getting this error on while running
pm2 start ecosystem.js
checked the logs via pm2 logs

```
0|backend  | Error: Could not load js config file /home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/config/env/production/database.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')

0|backend  |     at loadJsFile (/home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js:20:11)

0|backend  |     at loadFile (/home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js:37:14)

0|backend  |     at /home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/config-loader.js:18:18

0|backend  |     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

0|backend  |     at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/config-loader.js:15:6)

0|backend  |     at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/index.js:58:21)

0|backend  |     at new Strapi (/home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:75:23)

0|backend  |     at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:539:18)

0|backend  |     at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/<PROJECT>/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/start.js:23:10)
```

here the database.js file

```
const parse = require("pg-connection-string").parse;
const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      host: config.host,
      port: config.port,
      database: config.database,
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    },
    debug: false,
  },
});
```

Than I tried with Original JS File shown via Tutorial

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({   connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "<VAR>"),
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "<VAR>"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "<VAR>"),
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "<VAR>"),
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,   }, });
```

Still the same error.

Node version tried are following:

-- 14.x.x

-- 16.x.x

Comment: are you sure you are configuring this url variable as well?
`const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);`
I feel it might be undefined.